# Determine programmatically if a function call refers to your own function or a package's (or base R's) function?

Tags: r, call

What is the best way to programmatically figure out if a function call refers to your own function or a package's (or base R's) function?

Basically, I'm writing my own error recover function, and I want to allow the user to only see traceback messages for the functions that the user (I) have written.

```
foo = function(x){
  # do stuff
  return(x)
}
my_call = call('foo', 10)
R_call = call('round', 10.5)
library(gdata)
pkg_call = call('trim', ' _ ')
attributes(my_call) # NULL
attributes(R_call) # NULL
attributes(pkg_call) # NULL
```

Is there any way to programmatically differentiate between `my_call`, `pkg_call`, and `R_call`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible ways to achieve that is to use `getAnywhere` from `utils` package and determine where the called function is defined (user function will always be defined in `.GlobalEnv` and will mask other definitions). For example,

```
> foo = function(x){
+     # do stuff
+     return(x)
+ }
> my_call = call('foo', 10)
> R_call = call('round', 10.5)
> library(gdata)
> pkg_call = call('trim', ' _ ')
> is_user_function_call <- function(call) '.GlobalEnv' %in% getAnywhere(as.character(call[[1]]))$where
> is_user_function_call(my_call)
[1] TRUE
> is_user_function_call(R_call)
[1] FALSE
> is_user_function_call(pkg_call)
[1] FALSE
```

Essentially what `is_user_function` does is checks whether the called function is defined in `.GlobalEnv`.

When using the `getAnywhere`, there is essentially no difference between functions in base packages and other packages:

```
> getAnywhere('round')$where
[1] "package:base"   "namespace:base"
> getAnywhere('trim')$where
[1] "package:gdata"   "namespace:gdata"
```

So if you want to do distinguish between functions base/recommended packages and third-party packages, you will need to be checking it against the list of the packages. Something like this

```
> ip <- installed.packages() 
> base.packages <- ip[ ip[,"Priority"] %in% c("base"), "Package"]
> recommended.packages <- ip[ ip[,"Priority"] %in% c("recommended"), "Package"]
> is_base_function_call <- function(call) any(sapply(base.packages, grepl, x=getAnywhere(as.character(call[[1]]))$where))
> is_recommended_function_call <- function(call) any(sapply(recommended.packages, grepl, x=getAnywhere(as.character(call[[1]]))$where))
> is_package_function_call <- function(call) !is_user_function_call(call) && !is_base_function_call(call) && !is_recommended_function_call(call)
> is_base_function_call(R_call)
[1] TRUE
> is_base_function_call(pkg_call)
[1] FALSE
> is_package_function_call(pkg_call)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ls` and `search` functions, you could do something like this to attach as an attribute the namespace of the function to the expression generated by `call`.

```
call_with_ns <- function(name, ...) {
    found_namespace <- NA_character_
    for (namespace in search()) {
        if (name %in% ls(namespace)) {
            found_namespace <- namespace
            break
        }
    }

    result <- do.call(call, c(name, list(...)))
    attr(result, 'namespace') <- found_namespace
    result
}

foo = function(x){
  # do stuff
  return(x)
}
my_call = call_with_ns('foo', 10)
R_call = call_with_ns('round', 10.5)
library(gdata)
pkg_call = call_with_ns('trim', ' _ ')
attributes(my_call)
# $namespace
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"
attributes(R_call) 
# $namespace
# [1] "package:base"
attributes(pkg_call) 
# $namespace
# [1] "package:gdata"
```